# PyQGIS: How to color raster layer with existing colorBrewerMap

Tags: python, pyqgis, color

With pyqgis I have added multiple new raster layers to the legendinterface().
Because i like the ColorBrewer style i want to color some of them with the "**Spectral**" gradient.

How can I do this in python? The [API-help](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/raster.html) only gives advice how to color with individual set colorramps.
I found out that I can query the existing Ramps with `QgsColorBrewerPalette.listSchemes()`, but how can I set this style for my layer?

```
qshade = QgsColorRampShader()
qshade.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.INTERPOLATED)
qshade.setColorRampItemList("Spectral") # Similar to this?
```